# How to automatically update the IBM cognos Framework manager metadata?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I am new to IBM Cognos, I have created a project using DB2 as a data source. When I added some extra rows to my table it's not reflecting into my project. Is there any way to automatically update the database data into Cognos Report studio.
Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Extra rows not appearing would relate to recordsets being cached.  Try disabling the "Caching" option on the query in your report if you need it to always show the most current data.

Comment: Do you maybe mean columns, not rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its rows you are adding to your Query subject, they will automatically update in your framework manager metadata. You can check it by using Test tab.